# How to ensure that cgroup is limiting memory usage?

Tags: memory-management, cgroups

I have installed cgroup-tools and wanted to limit the memory usage for an application I'm running.
I have populated /etc/cgconfig.conf with the following table:

```
group mygroup {
  memory {
    memory.limit_in_bytes = 1073741824;
  }
}
```

Also populated /etc/cgrules.conf with:

```
*:my_app         memory      mygroup
```

So when I run the program my_app, I first check to make sure that the memory usage is using the behavior I have defined. So:

cat /proc/'pidof my_app'/cgroup | grep mygroup

Shows that memory usage is using mygroup constraints.
However when I check the memory usage using 'sudo pmap myapp_id' I get a number which is clearly larger than the limit I have set.

So the question is, what should I do to ensure that the memory usage of my program stays within the limit I defined in the cgroup config files?

Comment: I assume the limit is applying to real memory used (RSS), rather than just the amount of memory mapped.